# General form of the triangle inequality

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

We know that $$|z_1+z_2|\ge||z_1|-|z_2||$$
What about:
$$|z_1+z_2+\dots+z_n|\ge||z_1|-|z_2|-\dots-|z_n||$$
Is it correct to generalize the first inequality? How to prove it by induction? What I get is
$$|z_1+z_2+\dots+z_m+z_{m+1}|\ge|z_1+z_2+\dots+z_m|-|z_{m+1}||$$
$z_n$ are complex numbers.

Comment: Try $(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4) = (1, -1, 1, -1)$ ...

Comment: There is this generalization https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82207988.pdf